# Unusual freezing

Tags: freeze

My PC is randomly freezing. Sometimes it works fine for a few days and sometimes the freeze happens right after boot.

Most commonly, when the freeze happens everything keeps working behind the scenes for a couple more seconds. If I'm listening to music, it continues to play. When I hit ALT + SysRq + F it stops. During this time I perform the REISUB rescue sequence and it works.

On rare occasions, the system immediately becomes completely unresponsive.

How can I begin to diagnose the problem?

Steps taken:

- `free` reports enough available space

Comment: have you tried running the `free` command to see how much space is left? Even if you think it is a non-issue, a rogue app can persist a memory card worth of junk data pretty quickly. It is worth checking.

Comment: Output:

`Mem:
total: 8072000
used: 3771368
free: 739108
shared: 153872
buff/cache: 3561524
available: 3848400

Swap:

total: 2097148
used: 0
free: 2097148

Is this good or bad?`

Comment: good at the moment. the values change, programs write to memory. when one goes haywire, those values change quickly. When you notice it starting to freeze, try going into a tty (`ctrl` + `alt` + `f4` any f key 2-9 will work) and running the same command.

Comment: You wont really be able to do much until it starts happening, except checking logs. The logs are all stored in `/var/log/`. you can check the entire file with `cat [filepath] | less`. This will start you at the top and you use arrow keys to navigate

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at the logs. This can be done with commands like `dmesg` and `journalctl`. The fact that the freeze is slightly delayed is a big advantage here. This should give you at least a basic idea of what your problem is.

If it is freezing, it is most likely due to memory issues. There are a lot of memory issue troubleshooting commands built into linux. These include `vmstat`, `free`, and `stat /proc/meminfo`. The last is just printing out the data from a 'file.' The reason that it works is because /proc contains 'live files'(that is what I call them, anyway.) They usually represent real world things or concepts which change regularly, so they are constantly streaming. In other words, the output of this (and all listed) command(s) changes each time it is called.

Some more useful commands here are process based (as the last one above.) As processes use memory, these sort of overlap with those already mentioned. These include `top`, `ps`, and `htop`.

`top` in particular reminds me of `ctrl alt delete` on Windows systems. It shows all processes, and brings the memory hogs to the top. It can help to find a program that is causing issues.

Most importantly, to find out details about any of these commands, just type

```
man [command]
```

into the terminal, where `[command]` represents the command.

Comment: `dmesg` and `journalctl` show nothing wrong, or I am not technical enough to notice. `free` and `vmstat` show that there is still enough space. `stat /proc/meminfo` says that the file is empty. None of the process displayed by `top`, `ps` or `htop` seem to be causing trouble

Comment: All this while it is freezing / frozen? If the issue is not currently happening or just before, then all will be normal. The loggers usually only backlog for a few hours hours. Depends on how much is happening. Check `/var/logs`. If it is not currently happening, this is your best chance.

Comment: You don't have **Steam for Linux** installed by chance, do you?

Comment: I'm unable to get any feedback while the system is frozen. Things may run in the background for a little while but the screen isn't updating, I'm operating blind. And yes, I do have steam installed

Comment: Try entering tty. Sometimes that works when nothing else does. instructions above. f2-9 enters. f1 exits to login...  barring that,you can use `cat [log-pathname] | grep [term]` to search any term in any log. also, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356884/why-is-x86-split-lock-detection-spamming-my-syslog/1356917#1356917).